# Elasticsearch connection refused (dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200 ) - Articulate v0.21.2 Release

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, articulate, conversational-ui

I am trying to install Articulate v0.21.2
I pulled the latest from github by following the steps from
[Articulate Website](https://samtecspg.github.io/articulate/getting_started/basic-installation)
Installed Docker Toolbox on Windows 7.
On running docker-compose up , I am getting a
Elasticsearch connection refused (dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200)
Do you require to install elasticsearch seperately ?
How do I solve the below problem

Any help. complete trail below:

```
C:\Users\ss00346355\Desktop\articulate-v0.21.2>docker-compose up
Starting articulate-v0212_redis_1 ... done
Starting articulate-v0212_duckling_1 ... done
Starting articulate-v0212_rasa_1 ... done
Starting articulate-v0212_elasticsearch_1 ... done
Starting articulate-v0212_api_1 ... done
Starting articulate-v0212_ui_1 ... done
Attaching to articulate-v0212_ui_1, articulate-v0212_duckling_1, articulate-v0212_api_1, articulate-v0212_redis_1, articulate-v0212_rasa_1, articulate-v0212_el
sticsearch_1
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:56:56 Waiting for: http://elasticsearch:9200
redis_1 | 1:C 27 Apr 09:56:56.444 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis_1 | 1:C 27 Apr 09:56:56.446 # Redis version=4.0.6, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis_1 | 1:C 27 Apr 09:56:56.447 # Configuration loaded
redis_1 | 1:M 27 Apr 09:56:56.463 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis_1 | 1:M 27 Apr 09:56:56.467 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lowe
value of 128.
redis_1 | 1:M 27 Apr 09:56:56.470 # Server initialized
redis_1 | 1:M 27 Apr 09:56:56.472 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add
vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:56:56 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:56:57 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:56:58 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
duckling_1 | no port specified, defaulting to port 8000
ui_1 | yarn run v1.13.0
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:56:59 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:00 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:01 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
ui_1 | $ cross-env NODE_ENV=production env-cmd .env node server
ui_1 | Server started ! √
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:02 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:03 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:04 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:05 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
rasa_1 | 2019-04-27 09:57:07+0000 [-] Log opened.
rasa_1 | 2019-04-27 09:57:07+0000 [-] Site starting on 5000
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:06 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:07 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:08 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
elasticsearch_1 | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:09 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:10 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:09,599][WARN ][o.e.c.l.LogConfigurator ] [unknown] Some logging configurations have %marker but don't have %node_name. We
will automatically add %node_name to the pattern to ease the migration for users who customize log4j2.properties but will stop this behavior in 7.0. You should
manually replace %node_name with [%node_name]%marker in these locations:
elasticsearch_1 | /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/log4j2.properties
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:12,544][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment ] [Fy-UkXS] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/c/Users
]], net usable_space [27.6gb], net total_space [162.3gb], types [vboxsf]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:12,546][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment ] [Fy-UkXS] heap size [503.6mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:12,575][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [Fy-UkXS] node name derived from node ID [Fy-UkXS_QPuGSsULTNsO-A]; set [node.nam
] to override
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:12,578][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [Fy-UkXS] version[6.5.1], pid[1], build[default/tar/8c58350/2018-11-16T02:22:42.
82257Z], OS[Linux/4.14.111-boot2docker/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/11.0.1/11.0.1+13]
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:11 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:12 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:13 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:14 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:15 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:16 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:12,579][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [Fy-UkXS] JVM arguments [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiat
ngOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX
-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEna
led=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch.qaJv6FG3, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/
s_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT, -XX:UseAVX=2, -D
s.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Xms512m, -Xmx512m, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config, -Des.distribution.
lavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=tar]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,424][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,433][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [analysis-common]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,434][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [ingest-common]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,435][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [lang-expression]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,439][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [lang-mustache]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,440][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [lang-painless]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,441][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [mapper-extras]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,441][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [parent-join]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,443][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [percolator]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,444][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [rank-eval]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,448][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [reindex]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,449][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [repository-url]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,450][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [transport-netty4]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,451][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [tribe]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,453][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [x-pack-ccr]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,454][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [x-pack-core]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,455][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [x-pack-deprecation]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,460][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [x-pack-graph]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,460][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [x-pack-logstash]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,462][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [x-pack-ml]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,462][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [x-pack-monitoring]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,463][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [x-pack-rollup]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,463][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [x-pack-security]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,464][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [x-pack-sql]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,465][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [x-pack-upgrade]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,465][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]
elasticsearch_1 | [2019-04-27T09:57:18,467][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService ] [Fy-UkXS] loaded plugin [ingest-geoip]
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:17 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:18 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:19 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:20 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:22 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:23 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:24 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:25 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:26 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:27 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:28 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:29 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:30 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:31 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:32 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:33 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:34 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:35 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
api_1 | 2019/04/27 09:57:37 Problem with request: Get http://elasticsearch:9200: dial tcp 172.20.0.6:9200: connect: connection refused. Sleeping 1s
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping articulate-v0212_api_1 ... done
Stopping articulate-v0212_ui_1 ... done
Stopping articulate-v0212_rasa_1 ... done
Stopping articulate-v0212_elasticsearch_1 ... done
Stopping articulate-v0212_duckling_1 ... done
Stopping articulate-v0212_redis_1 ... done
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually isn't an error at all. Articulate uses Dockerize to wait until Elasticsearch has started before starting the API. Elasticsearch can often take > 90 seconds to startup.

It looks to me like you just didn't wait long enough for everything to start up.

Other possible problems:

- Not enough memory allocated to Docker (ES and Rasa are memory hungry. We recommend a minimum of 4G)
- Not Enough Hard Drive Space (ES will not accept new writes if it has too little space)
- Bad Permissions (Sometimes ES in Docker needs a user specified)

All of these should be obvious if you include a link to a gist and let the startup run for >5 minutes. Post that and I can try to help further.

If you need more help, please feel free to [create an issue](https://github.com/samtecspg/articulate/issues/new) on Articulate's repo or [join us on Discord](https://discord.gg/YCpaPpv).